# how to avoid multiple IF statements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

i would like to shorten the code here.
i want the number after quiz to change according to the number stored in the variable 'counter' so  that i dont have to repeat so many times.

```
        if (counter==2) {
            var question = document.quiz1.quiz.value;
            console.log(question);
        }
        if (counter==3) {
            var question = document.quiz2.quiz.value;
            console.log(question);
        }
        if (counter==4) {
            var question = document.quiz3.quiz.value;
            console.log(question);
        }
        if (counter==5) {
            var question = document.quiz4.quiz.value;
            console.log(question);
        }
```

Comment: `document[\`quiz${counter - 1}\`]`?

Comment: Try to search for Select Case in JavaScript. Also declare the var question only once at first line before everything.

Comment: why not using an array of quizzes instead of a variable for each quiz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
if (counter>1 && counter<6) {
        var question = document['quiz'+counter].quiz.value;
        console.log(question);
    }
```

feel free to ask more question in comment

Comment: thank you sooo much. this was troubling me for days.

Answer (score -1):

**not particularly shorter but a cleaner solution:**

```
 var question;
    switch(counter) {
      case 1:
      question = document.quiz1.quiz.value;
    case 2:
      question = document.quiz2.quiz.value;
    case 3:
      question = document.quiz3.quiz.value;
    case 4:
      question = document.quiz4.quiz.value;
    console.log(question);
```